# How do I make an actor move to the foreground temporarily in LibGDX scene2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, gui, scene2d, inventory

I have an inventory UI which is a table in scene2d. Then the table had a bunch of Containers which are basically inventory slots. They have a transparant grey background color. Then in each container is an ItemStack with a picture of an item and a stacksize. When I pull this ItemStack over a container that was created later, it moves behind the container and the transparant grey background will be in front of the item picture. How do I temporarily (or permanently) move it to the foreground so it doesn't matter in front of which container I drag the item?

Example of what happens:
https://i.imgur.com/yq4njex.gifv

This is how I create the containers:

```
// Create inventory slots
table.row();
inventorySlots.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < inventory.getInventorySize(); i++) {
    if (i % SLOTS_PER_ROW == 0) table.row();

    Container cont = new Container();
    cont.fill();
    cont.background(Utils.createDrawable(1, 1, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.4f)));

    inventorySlots.add(cont);
    table.add(cont).prefHeight(50).prefWidth(50).pad(5);
}
```

After that I add each ItemStack to the list of containers/inventoryslots like this:

```
// Add ItemStacks from Items to their respective slot
ArrayList<Item> items = inventory.getItems();
for(Container slot : inventorySlots) {
    Item item = items.get(inventorySlots.indexOf(slot));

    if(item != null) {
        ItemStack itemStack = new ItemStack(item);
        addInventoryEvent(itemStack, items);
        slot.pad(5);
        slot.setActor(itemStack);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ZIndex of an Actor describes its position in respect to its siblings (other Actors in the same Group)

you can manipulate it with `Actor.setZIndex()`. There are also convienience methods for your usecase:
`Actor.toFront()` and  `Actor.toBack()`

The Group class has methods to add Actors in front or behind another Actor. It can allso swap the ZIndex of two of its children.

Comment: Yeah, this works. Thanks. However if the item needs to be drawn above another stage (Say the hotbar) and this stage is drawn later, I think there is no way to do this. Currently I'm using a flag that determines whether the hotbar or inventory should be drawn first, but I might consider not having multiple stages, but just edit 1 big stage.